# CSS Responsive Cropped Image

Tags: html, css

YouTube create a set of thumbnails for every uploaded video.  I'm using this one as an example (should have a 16:9 aspect ratio):

[image]

**My Aim**

I want to take 4 of these thumbnails and display them in 2 columns while losing the black lines at the top and bottom.  I'd rather use only CSS if possible (no JavaScript/JQuery unless absolutely necessary).  I can do this fairly easily using flexbox in CSS but as the viewport gets smaller, the black lines come into view.  I'm not even sure if it is possible to do what I want because the image height is variable.  Here's the code I've tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<style type='text/css'>

#video_outer {
    max-width:978px;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: left; 
    margin-top: 0;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap
}

#video_outer .video {
    width:100%; 
    height:270px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    flex:0 calc(50% - 5px);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background: white url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ENe89j89tBA/hqdefault.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

#video_outer .right_margin_10 {margin-right:10px}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="video_outer">
  
  <div class="video right_margin_10"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>

  <div class="video right_margin_10"></div>
  <div class="video"></div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mask or hide the black background from the video preview, you need to create a container with the same aspect ratio as @mohamed-mufeed commented.

Next, you can create a nested block element inside your `.video` wrapper(s). Important to remember here that your `.video` container must set `overflow: hidden` so `div.video` can "hide" the black areas on your image.

The key to all this in this particular example (others are available and hopefully others provide them) is that `.video` has `overflow: hidden` AND the `div` nested within `.video` has `height: 0` as well as the `padding-top: 52.25%` set. The `padding-top` sets the aspect ratio for your images uploaded to YouTube.

**A slightly modified version of your HTML/CSS below:**

```
#video_outer {
    max-width: 978px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.video {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.video:nth-of-type(odd) { padding-right: 5px; }
.video:nth-of-type(even) { padding-left: 5px; }
.video > div {
    padding-top: 52.25%;
    height: 0;
    background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ENe89j89tBA/hqdefault.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**A slight modification to your HTML as well**

```
<div id="video_outer">
  <div class="video">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see it in action with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3xj1qapb/1/